# Priority queue in Java - retrieve a particular element

Tags: java

I have a priority queue containing elements of a custom Type called Process. Each Process has 3 fields. I need to be able to retrieve a Process from my priority queue which has a particular value for one of its fields. How can I do this? poll() seems to always return the head of the queue.

Here is my code for the Process class:

```
package SPN;

public class Process implements Comparable<Process> {

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Process proc) {
        //implement this
        return 0;
    }

    private int arrive_time= 0;
    private int burst_time = 0;
    private int remain_time = 0;

    public Process (int arr_time, int bur_time) {

        this.arrive_time = arr_time;
        this.burst_time = bur_time;
    }

    public int getArrTime() {return arrive_time;}
    public int getBurTime() {return burst_time;}
    public int getRemTime() {return remain_time;}
}
```

In another class I have created a priority queue called prq and added processes with different values for the fields. Don't worry about the incomplete code. I just can't add everything, coz it will be pages of code. Something like this:

```
p1 = new Process(2, 10);
prq.add(p1);

p2 = new Process(1, 8);
prq.add(p2);

p3 = new Process(0, 11);
prq.add(p3);
```

I need to be able to retrieve process p3 because it has the earliest arrive_time. How can I do this? The following seems to retrieve and remove only the head of the priority queue. Don't reccomend using a different data structure, as that does not really work. Has to be a priority queue, because I need to do further selecting based on the other fields as well.

```
Process current = prq.poll();
```

Comment: You are using a priority queue, so why not use a Comparator?

Comment: @RedSonja is right, you should either pass `Comparator` to `ProirityQueue` constructor or properly implement `compareTo` method in `Process` class. E.g. like `return Integer.compare(arrive_time, proc.arrive_time);`. In this case queue's head will be what you need.

Comment: Where is your `compareTo` method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should implement the `compareTo` method like this:

```
@Override
public int compareTo(Process proc) {
  // this.arriveTime > proc.arriveTime --> >0
  // this.arriveTime < proc.arriveTime --> <0
  // this.arriveTime = proc.arriveTime --> 0
  return this.arriveTime - proc.arriveTime;
}
```

This way the items that have smaller `arriveTime` will come first.

Comment: I don't understand the commented part and why it is commented.

Comment: The comments are just to explain how the ```compareTo``` method will behave in different situations.

Comment: [PriorityQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html) in java uses a min heap, so you don't need to reverse the comparision.

Comment: Ok, I still don't understand why you are returning the result of subtracting one process's arrive time from another.

Comment: The compare method returns an int value. If the value is 0, it means ```this``` is equal to the given object. If the value is <0 - ```this``` is lower than the given object. If the value is >0 - ```this``` is greater than the given object.

Comment: Ok cool. So how does it know which object I want it to return based on the values?

Comment: The ```PriorityQueue``` uses a heap to sort the data that is given. When you call ```poll``` it returns the *smaller* element in the queue. The ```compareTo``` method is used during the sorting process.

Comment: The arrive time for the earliest one will always be smaller than the later one. So the compareTo will return:
Negative if the object "this" arrived earlier.
Positive if the object "this" arrived later.
0 if they arrived at the very same time.

You should also read the Comparable interface if you don't understand this.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html

Comment: @RumenHristov, if this works for you, may I ask you to accept the answer as the correct one? :)

Comment: after I implement the compareTo as above, will I always get the process with least arrive_time when I call poll() on the queue?

Comment: Yes, the collection is sorted. Take in mind that once the ```Process``` instance is polled from the queue, it is removed from it. If you don't want to remove it, you can use the ```peek``` method.

Answer (score 3):

The reason I see here is because you have unfinished implementation of compareTo() method in Process class. Since its always zero being returned, the retrieval is in the order of insertion as its considering every object to be equal.

You could complete the implementation as below

```
public void compareTo(Process proc) 
{
    if (this.getArrTime() < proc.getArrTime()) {
        return -1;
    else if (this.getArrTime() > proc.getArrTime()) {
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: The reason you are always seeing the head (the first element inserted) is because java.util.PriorityQueue preserves the natural ordering. Refer the javadoc http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/java_util_priorityqueue.htm for more details

Comment: A typo: the second branch should be `return 1;`

Comment: I was gonna ask the OP about that. :) You were first to mention.

Comment: @RumenHristov can you please elaborate OP ? (output ??) Anyways, I hope it worked and solved your problem

Comment: OP = Original Poster. In this case it refers to you, as you are the one who provided this answer and made the typo.

Answer (score 1):

It is not necessary for `Process` class to implement `Comparable<Process>` interface:

```
public class Process {
    private int arrive_time= 0;
    private int burst_time = 0;
    private int remain_time = 0;

    public Process (int arr_time, int bur_time) {
        this.arrive_time = arr_time;
        this.burst_time = bur_time;
    }

    public int getArrTime() {return arrive_time;}
    public int getBurTime() {return burst_time;}
    public int getRemTime() {return remain_time;}
}
```

Your `PriorityQueue` which named `prq` can be initialized like:

```
PriorityQueue<Process> prq = new PriorityQueue<Process>(new Comparator<Process>() {
    // arrive_time in ascending order
    @Override
    public int compare(Process p1, Process p2) {
        return p1.arrive_time - p2.arrive_time;
    }
});
```

Then:

```
  Process p1 = new Process(2, 10);
  prq.add(p1);

  Process p2 = new Process(1, 8);
  prq.add(p2);

  Process p3 = new Process(0, 11);
  prq.add(p3);

  System.out.println(prq.poll().getArrTime()); // output is 0 (which means p3)
  System.out.println(prq.poll().getArrTime()); // output is 1 (which means p2)
```

Comment: prq = new PriorityQueue<Process>(10, new Comparator<Process>()    What does the 10 mean?

Comment: @RumenHristov It means the initialCapacity, please see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html

Comment: @RumenHristov In fact, the initialCapacity paramter is not necessary, I have updated the answer.

Comment: This gives me the following error: The constructor PriorityQueue<Process>(new Comparator<Process>(){}) is undefined. Adding 10 as previously solves the error, but what exactly does the 10 do?

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of a PriorityQueue is to have a collection of elements sorted by their priority. In your case processes that have arrived earliest have the highest priority. When adding an element to a PriorityQueue it will be compared to the other elements that are already in the queue and put in the right place.

Now I feel like we are still a little unclear about comparing objects, so here's a little explanation to that: 
The compare method (which you have to implement because of the Comparator interface) always returns an int value, that is either < 0, equal to 0 or > 0.

- equal to 0 means the two values compared are equal to each other
- > 0 means that this is "greater" than the object given as a parameter
- < 0 means that this is "smaller" than the object given as a parameter

Now as I already mentioned, the queue will compare the value you are trying to insert to the values that are already in the queue, according to your compare method.

So all you have to do is to properly implement your compare method, as Kiril Aleksandrov already explained.

Refer to the Oracle Docs https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html